# What is the difference between a and &a for arguments passed to printf?

Tags: c, pointers, printf, memory-address

As a tiny example, I get two different values for the first printf and the 2nd printf.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int a;
      
  a = 100;
      
  printf("%p\t%x\n", &a, &a);
  printf("%p\t%x\n", a, a);
  return 0;
}
```

I believe I understand what the first printf is doing, it is printing the address of a, but why do I get a different value of I just put in a without the ampersand?

Edit: I think I managed to figure out what the 2nd printf was doing. It was printing the actual value of what a was, only in hexadecimal format. Converting the result to decimal was the same as what I posted. This question can be closed now.

Comment: `printf` format specifiers have to match the types of the corresponding arguments passed.  Using `%x` and passing a pointer, or using `%p` and passing an int, cause undefined behavior.  And for that matter `%x` is supposed to take `unsigned int`, not `int`, so that's technically undefined behavior as well (though on many systems it works anyway).

Answer (score 1):

My compiler says this about the code:

```
../main.c:9:14: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
    9 |     printf("%p\t%x\n", &a, &a);
      |             ~^         ~~
      |              |         |
      |              void *    int *
      |             %ls
../main.c:9:18: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
    9 |     printf("%p\t%x\n", &a, &a);
      |                 ~^         ~~
      |                  |         |
      |                  |         int *
      |                  unsigned int
      |                 %ls
../main.c:10:14: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   10 |     printf("%p\t%x\n", a, a);
      |             ~^         ~
      |              |         |
      |              void *    int
      |             %d
```

So for `gcc` (if used) try adding the folling handy options to your compile command line `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion` and you'll get a lot of free feedback.
E.g.

```
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu2x -o main.o -c main.c
```

This version of your program might be more meaningful

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 100;
    printf("%p\t%lx\n", (void *) &a, (uintptr_t) &a);
    printf("%d\t%x\n", a, a);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Please note the changes in the formatting strings.